# Object Oriented Design/How to set up class structure

Tags: java, oop

I am fairly new to object oriented programming and I am curious to know at a high level how to solve this problem.

If I have a list of  different calendars i.e. work calendar, personal calendar, sports calendars, etc and each of them have there own respective events. I assume I would have a calendar class and then the nested class would be the event class.  Since I want to display all of the events from all the calendars on one list they would all go into on sorted array.  But lets say I wanted to delete one of my calendars like my work calendar how would I ensure that all the work events were deleted from this list/array.  I am curious to how this class structure would be set up at a high level.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To my mind, you would start with a basic concept of a calendar and event.  I would then create a new calendar for each group of events (ie work, personal, etc).  It would then define some kind "visual" component which was capable of displaying one or more calendars.  That way, when you delete a calendar, you simply remove the instance you no longer want, leaving the rest alone.

Comment: Take a look at the Composite Design Pattern.

Answer (score 1):

If I am to do your requirement, I will have the following line up :

```
interface Calendar 
class DefaultCalendar implements Calendar //<- default implementation for calendar. will hold the implementation for the common behavior for all the calendars
class PersonalCalendar implements Calendar //<- implementation for calendar that holds personal events, decorator for DefaultCalendar
class SportsCalendar implements Calendar //<- implementation for calendar that holds sports events, decorator for DefaultCalendar
class WorkCalendar implements Calendar //<- implementation for calendar that holds work events, decorator for DefaultCalendar
class Event //<- the event object, setters & getters
class CalendarManager //<- object for adding, removing calendars
```

I will use `TreeMap` which is an implementation of `SortedMap` to utilise the natural order of the events to be put.

`Map<String, Calendar> calendars = new TreeMap<String, Calendar>();`

I will also prepend the event names with words specific to the calendar to group the events by calendar type (thus, event type) when displaying

```
@Override public void addEvent(Event event){
    //event.setName("Work Event : " + event.getEventName()); for work event
    //event.setName("Sports Event : " + event.getEventName()); for sports event
    //event.setName("Personal Event : " + event.getEventName()); for personal event
    calendar.addEvent(event);
}
```

Thus, when the manager is asked to display all the events, will result to

```
Personal Event : blah blah blah abc 123
Personal Event : blah blah blah abc 123
Sports Event : blah blah blah abc 123
Work Event : blah blah blah abc 123
```

Now, to demonstrate what I'm saying, here are my runnable codes

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

/* the demo class */

public class CalendarDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException{
        CalendarManager manager = new CalendarManager();

        Calendar mySportsCalendar = new SportsCalendar(new DefaultCalendar());
        Calendar myWorkCalendar = new WorkCalendar(new DefaultCalendar());
        Calendar myPersonalCalendar = new PersonalCalendar(new DefaultCalendar());

        Event myBirthday = new Event("My 23rd Birthday Celebration", "September 17, 2013", "This marks my 23rd birthday celebration!");
        Event myMothersBirthday = new Event("My Mother's 50th Birthday Celebration", "December 19, 2013", "This marks my mothers 50th birthday celebration!");

        Event tennisGame = new Event("Tennis Game With Denver", "August 11, 2013", "3rd tennis game with my nephew.");

        Event newProjectMeeting = new Event("New Project Meeting", "August 11, 2013", "Meeting with our new project.");

        myPersonalCalendar.addEvent(myBirthday);
        myPersonalCalendar.addEvent(myMothersBirthday);
        myWorkCalendar.addEvent(newProjectMeeting);
        mySportsCalendar.addEvent(tennisGame);

        manager.addCalendar("sportsCalendar", mySportsCalendar);
        manager.addCalendar("workCalendar", myWorkCalendar);
        manager.addCalendar("personalCalendar", myPersonalCalendar);

        System.out.println("Before the removal of personal calendar : ");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(manager.displayAllCalendarEvents());

        manager.removeCalendar("personalCalendar"); //<- will delete all the events in personalCalendar;

        System.out.println("After the removal of personal calendar : ");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(manager.displayAllCalendarEvents());
    }
}

/* the calendar interface */

interface Calendar{
    Event getEvent(String eventName);
    List<Event> getEvents();
    void addEvent(Event event);
    String getDescription();
    void setDescription(String desc);
}

/* the default implementation of calendar */

class DefaultCalendar implements Calendar{

    private List<Event> events;
    private String description;

    public DefaultCalendar(){
        events = new ArrayList<Event>();
    }

    @Override public Event getEvent(String eventName) {

        for(Event event : events){
            if(event.getEventName().equals(eventName))
                return event;
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Event name does not exist in the event list.");
    }

    @Override public void addEvent(Event event) {
        events.add(event);
    }

    @Override public String getDescription(){
        return description;
    }

    @Override public void setDescription(String desc){
        description = desc;
    }

    @Override public List<Event> getEvents() {
        return events;
    }
}

/* decorators for defaultcalendar. If you want
 * specific behavior for a specific calendar, you can
 * specify it in these classes.
 * ---------------------------------------------- */

class SportsCalendar implements Calendar{

    private Calendar calendar;

    public SportsCalendar(Calendar baseCalendar){
        calendar = baseCalendar;
    }

    @Override public String getDescription(){
        return calendar.getDescription();
    }

    @Override public void addEvent(Event event){
        event.setEventName("Sports Event : " + event.getEventName());
        calendar.addEvent(event);
    }

    @Override public Event getEvent(String eventName) {
        return calendar.getEvent("Sports Event : " + eventName);
    }

    @Override public void setDescription(String desc) {

        //do something to the passed desc
        //...
        //then pass it to the wrapped calendar;

        calendar.setDescription(desc);
    }

    @Override public List<Event> getEvents() {
        return calendar.getEvents();
    }
}

/* another decorator */

class WorkCalendar implements Calendar{

    private Calendar calendar;

    public WorkCalendar(Calendar baseCalendar){
        calendar = baseCalendar;
    }

    @Override public String getDescription(){
        return calendar.getDescription();
    }

    @Override public void addEvent(Event event){
        event.setEventName("Work Event : " + event.getEventName());
        calendar.addEvent(event);
    }

    @Override public Event getEvent(String eventName) {
        return calendar.getEvent("Work Event : " + eventName);
    }

    @Override public void setDescription(String desc){

        //do something to the passed desc
        //...
        //then pass it to the wrapped calendar;

        calendar.setDescription(desc);
    }

    @Override public List<Event> getEvents() {
        return calendar.getEvents();
    }
}

/* another decorator */

class PersonalCalendar implements Calendar{

    private Calendar calendar;

    public PersonalCalendar(Calendar baseCalendar){
        calendar = baseCalendar;
    }

    @Override public String getDescription(){
        return calendar.getDescription();
    }

    @Override public void addEvent(Event event){
        event.setEventName("Personal Event : " + event.getEventName());
        calendar.addEvent(event);
    }

    @Override public Event getEvent(String eventName) {
        return calendar.getEvent("Personal Event : " + eventName);
    }

    @Override public void setDescription(String desc) {

        //do something to the passed desc
        //...
        //then pass it to the wrapped calendar;

        calendar.setDescription(desc);
    }

    @Override public List<Event> getEvents() {
        return calendar.getEvents();
    }
}

/* the calendar manager, for adding & removing calendars */

class CalendarManager{

    private Map<String, Calendar> calendars;

    public CalendarManager(){
        calendars = new TreeMap<String, Calendar>();
    }

    public void addCalendar(String key, Calendar calendar){
        calendars.put(key, calendar);
    }

    public void removeCalendar(String key){
        calendars.remove(key);
    }

    public String displayAllCalendarEvents(){
        StringBuilder bdr = new StringBuilder();

        for(String key : calendars.keySet()){
            for(Event event : calendars.get(key).getEvents()){
                bdr.append(event.getEventName())
                .append("\t")
                .append(event.getEventDate())
                .append("\t")
                .append(event.getEventDescription())
                .append("\n");
            }
        }

        return bdr.toString();
    }
}

/* the event object */

class Event{

    private String name;
    private Date date;
    private String description;

    public Event(String name, String date, String description){
        this.name = name;
        try {
            this.date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse("December 19, 2013");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid date format!");
        }
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getEventName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Date getEventDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public String getEventDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setEventName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setEventDate(String date) {
        try {
            this.date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse("December 19, 2013");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid date format!");
        }
    }

    public void setEventDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would go about it, the highlighted parts are what I would pick up on:

If I have a list of different `calendars` i.e. `work calendar`, `personal calendar`, `sports calendars`, etc and each of them have there own respective `events`. Since I want to display all of the events from all the calendars on one `list` they would all go into on sorted array. But lets say I wanted to `delete one of my calendars` like my work calendar how would I ensure that all the `work events were deleted` from this list/array.

That gives me:

```
emum CalendarType
{
    WORK,
    PERSONAL,
    SPORT,
}

class Event
{
    // event data, like time, place, people, etc...
    private Calendar owner;
}

class Calendar
{
    private CalendarType type; // or make this a String and get rid of the enum 
                               // if people can make their own types
    private List<Event> event;s
}
```

The part about wanting to have all the events in a single list and delete them when the calendar is a bit harder.

I think what I would do is add a method like this in a `CalendarUtils` class:

```
public static void deleteEvents(Calendar c, List<Event> events)
{
    // loop through all the events, for each one from the calendar remove it
}
```

Comment: I can see a circular reference and a strong coupling.

Comment: Because calendar knows event, and event knows calendar?  Maybe odd, but not at all wrong.  It can always be removed by adding a CalendarEvent class that has references to both instead.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to nest your classes. Just create one class, as MadProgrammer was suggesting, that is an event, implement that to your Calendar class and use it as needed. If you wanted to delete a calendar, you might include some method that makes sure to delete all events from inside that calendar. But just deleting the calendar object should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class BaseCalendar{//do some common functionality here or define the abstract methods so child class will provide the implementation }
public class WorkCalendar extends BaseCalendar{//do WorkCalendar specific functionality here}
public class PersonalCalendar extends BaseCalendar{//do Personalcalendar specific functionality here}
public class SportsCalendar extends BaseCalendar{//do Sportscalendar specific functionality here}
create another class for Events and create list of events for each calendar(use aggrgation here, once your calendar is destroyed your events will also destroyed)
```

thsi will be the approach I will take if your each calendar have different behaviour.